# Web Scraping with BS4, select by div id still returns entire page

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape from wikipedia's current events page here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portal:Current_events . Specifically the current date. Using inspect element I can see that all the information I want is stored in the a div with the id "2020_June_15". In my script I specify that specific id, however my current script continues to pull everything from the page. What am I missing?

Here is the python script wiki.py:

```
import sys
import requests
import bs4

res = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portal:Current_events')
res.raise_for_status()


soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
elems = soup.select('div', {"id": "2020_June_15"})
for i in range(len(elems)):
    print(elems[i].getText())
```

Comment: Try this `soup.select("[id='2020_June_15']")`, If you wanna stick to `.select()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace soup.select with soup.find_all

```
import sys
import requests
import bs4

res = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portal:Current_events')
res.raise_for_status()


soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
elems = soup.find_all('div', {"id": "2020_June_15"})
for i in range(len(elems)):
    print(elems[i].getText())
```

Answer (score 0):

You are really close.  Instead of "select" use "find"

```
import sys
import requests
import bs4

res = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portal:Current_events')
res.raise_for_status()

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
elems = soup.find('div', {"id": "2020_June_15"})
for i in range(len(elems)):
    print(elems[i].getText())
```

Comment: don't use the code tag, just select the text and press ctrl+k for code formatting.